# wp_mail() function taking too long to deliver single mail

Tags: php, wordpress, function, email

I have the following code which sends a single email to my account. However, this takes about 3-5 minutes after the user submits the form. Is there anyway to reduce the delivery time or is this just what the wp_mail() function takes all the time? This is my code:

```
    if ($_POST['task-title'] && $_POST['task-description'] && $_FILES['task-files']['size']<20971520){
    $mailto = array('example@email.com');
    $subject = 'Task "'.$_POST['task-title'].'" ('.$_POST['task-priority'].')';
    $body = 'Client: '.$user_name.'

    Task title: '.$_POST['task-title'].'            
    Category: '.$_POST['task-category'].'           
    Priority: '.$_POST['task-priority'].'

    Description:
    '.$_POST['task-description'];

    $headers = 'From: '.$user_name.'<'.$current_user->user_email.'>';
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["task-files"]['tmp_name'], WP_CONTENT_DIR.'/uploads/'.basename($_FILES['task-files']['name']));
    $attachments = array(WP_CONTENT_DIR."/uploads/".$_FILES["task-files"]['name']);   

    wp_mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments);
```

I thought about setting up a cronjob to send the unsent emails every minute but I'd be using wp_mail() again so it'd be the same anyways wouldn't it?

Comment: My guess is that the delay is with your hosting platform, and not with WP.

Answer (score 0):

If you sending attachment it will take time to send mail.
You can try one mail without attachment if it work fast then it definitely due to size of attachment.
Also check server connection.
CPU utilization.

Comment: I tried it before adding the attachments and it took the same time back then, but I'll check CPU utilization and server connection. Thanks.